# How to stop/start logstash service running in docker

Tags: docker, logstash

I'm trying to figure out how logstash works/run inside docker, and I'm stuck with simple thing like starting and stoping logstash.

I have started logstash docker container with simple run

```
docker run -it --name l2 logstash
```

and with result:

```
 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Next thing is runing /bin/bash with exec command, to get inside running container.

```
docker exec -it l2 /bin/bash 
root@1b55d3a40d3f:/#
```

Listing services status, shows that there is no logstash service running. 
Where can I find logstash service and stop/start?

```
root@1b55d3a40d3f:/# service --status-all 
 [ - ]  bootlogs
 [ - ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ - ]  checkfs.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  killprocs
 [ - ]  motd
 [ - ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  mountall.sh
 [ - ]  mountdevsubfs.sh
 [ - ]  mountkernfs.sh
 [ - ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  mountnfs.sh
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rc.local
 [ - ]  rmnologin
 [ - ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-finish
 [ - ]  umountfs
 [ - ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ - ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logstash in the container is not run as a system service, the entrypoint in the image will start a process and will keep the container up until this process ends or fails.

If you do a `docker top l2` it will show the logstash process running (probaly alone) in the container.

To stop the logstash, you need to stop the container with `docker stop l2`, and later when you need to start it again you can run `docker start l2`, it will work as long you set the containers name as l2 when you create or first run it.

Docker Start help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/

Docker stop help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

Docker create: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if this performs a controlled (graceful) shutdown? 

Basically, does the following happen:
- Stop all input, filter and output plugins
- Process all in-flight events
- Terminate the Logstash process

Comment: @DazBaldwin it should, by the `logstash` documentation it does the steps you listed when it receives a `SIGTERM`, and `docker stop` first sends a `SIGTERM`.

but if the process take too much time to stop (10 seconds), docker will `SIGKILL` it.

so there is too many in-flight events for example, it may be killed before doing all of that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/shutdown.html
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

Comment: Thanks for that, for further confirmation, I have also managed to get that confirmed on here: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/issues/518